# SharePoint 2010 - Default tagging of document in the document library

Tags: managed-metadata, tagging

Is there a way through which I can select the default tag for the all the document in a document library.

I am sure it can be done using a "ItemAdded" event redeiver,  just wondering if we can configure that using the OOB techniques.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Sudhir Kesharwani

Answer (score 1):

Look into SP2010 feature of Managed Metadata that can have default value when applied. Storing documents within a Document Set that has the Managed Metadata applied can propagate the metadata values to the documents in the Document Set.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way to set this since the tags are actually maintained by users and part of the user profile service. Adding a default tag to an item would have to be done under the context of a user.

Answer (score -1):

This might help

http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/10/retrieve-tags-and-notes-for-current.html

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! While this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for reference. See [How to Answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.